# Relating to tournaments.. what's that word?

Tags: single-word-requests

So, in a tournament, there are several events.  Each event has so many people sign up for it.  There is a total number of people attending the tournament, and each person can sign up for multiple events.

If Joe signs up for 2 events, and Mary signs up for 3, John signs up for 1...

There are 3 people/registrants, but 6 **somethings**. (2 + 3 + 1)

What is that **somethings**? (Does it even exist?)

Edit:

"Entries" *just* occurred to me as a possible answer.  I've been thinking about this all night and wonder what else is out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe 'event entries'. Possibly with a hyphen.

Comment: Yeah, probably the best I'm going to get.  All night for such a simple word.. it stumped my husband, too.

Answer (score 4):

Entries, as you suggested? Registrations?

Comment: +1 for Registrations. There are 3 registrants, who each registered for 2 events. Thus, 6 registrations.

Comment: +1 for Registrations. There are 3 "participants", who each registered for 2 events. Thus, 6 registrations. I think registrant sounds awful.

Comment: I'd have to disagree, actually.  If I'm collecting registrations for a tournament, each registrant can register on that registration form for multiple events making it unsuitable.  I suppose it would be fine if they had to register separately for each event.

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a case for **entrants** here. It associates more strongly with each *event*, rather than each *competitor*. I accept it's a little bit odd, but I don't have a big problem with the statement *Thus there are 6 entrants, but only 3 competitors*.

Comment: Hmmm.... entrant [ˈɛntrənt]
n
1. a person who enters
2. a new member of a group, society, or association
3. a person who enters a competition or contest; competitor.  All relate to the person unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a box of *match*? Depending on the context of the tournament, **matches** sounds quite alright, I think.